# Maintenance of reference counting in Z3

Tags: z3

By some reasons I have to use C++ API and C API of Z3 together. In C++ API, reference counting of Z3 objects are well maintained and I needn't to worry about making mistakes. However I have to manually maintain reference counting for Z3 objects when I use C API because C++ API uses `Z3_mk_context_rc` to create the context. I have several problems on reference counting maintenance in Z3.

(1) If the reference counting of a `Z3_ast` is reduced to 0, what is responsible to release the memory of this `Z3_ast`? And when?

(2) The code below

```
void rctry(context & c)
{
    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    expr y = c.int_const("y");

    Z3_ast res = Z3_mk_eq(c,x,y);
#ifdef FAULT_CLAUSE
    expr z = c.int_const("z");
    expr u = c.int_const("u");
    Z3_ast fe = Z3_mk_eq(c,z,u);
#endif
    std::cout << Z3_ast_to_string(c,res) << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    config cfg;
    cfg.set("MODEL", true);
    cfg.set("PROOF", true);
    context c(cfg);
    rctry(c)；
}
```

Although I didn't increase reference count for AST referenced by `res`, the program works well. If `FAULT_CLAUSE` is defined, program still works, but it will output `(= z u)` instead of `(= x y)`. How to explain this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My golden rule for reference counting is: Whenever my program receives a pointer to a Z3 object, I immediately increment the ref count and I save the object somewhere safe (i.e., I now own 1 reference to that object). Only when I'm absolutely sure that I will not need the object any longer, then I will call Z3_dec_ref; from that point on, any access to that object will trigger undefined behavior (not necessarily a segfault), because I don't own any references anymore - Z3 owns all the rerferences and it can do whatever it wants to do with them.

Z3 objects are always deallocated when the ref count goes to zero; it's within the call to dec_ref() that the deallocation happens. If Z3_dec_ref() is never called (like in the example given), then the object may remain in memory so accessing that particular part of the memory might perhaps still give "ok looking" results, but that part of the memory may also be overwritten by other procedures so that they contain garbage.

In the example program given, we would need to add inc/dec_ref calls as follows:

```
void rctry(context & c)
{
    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    expr y = c.int_const("y");

    Z3_ast res = Z3_mk_eq(c,x,y);
    Z3_inc_ref(c, res); // I own 1 ref to res!
#ifdef FAULT_CLAUSE
    expr z = c.int_const("z");
    expr u = c.int_const("u");
    Z3_ast fe = Z3_mk_eq(c,z,u);
    Z3_inc_ref(c, fe); I own 1 ref to fe!
#endif
    std::cout << Z3_ast_to_string(c, res) << std::endl;
#ifdef FAULT_CLAUSE
    Z3_dec_ref(c, fe); // I give up my ref to fe.
#endif
    Z3_dec_ref(c, res); // I give up my ref to res.
}
```

The explanation for the output `(= z u)` is that the second call to `Z3_mk_eq`
re-uses the chunk of memory that previously held `res`, because apparently
only the library itself had a reference to it, so it is free to chose what to
do with the memory. The consequence is that the call to `Z3_ast_to_string`
reads from the right part of the memory (that used to contain `res`), but the
contents of that part of the memory have changed in the meanwhile.

That was the long explanation for anybody who needs to manage ref counts in C. In
the case of C++ there is also a much more convenient way: the ast/expr/etc
objects contain a constructor that takes C objects. Therefore, we can construct
managed objects by simply wrapping them in constructor calls; in this
particular example that could be done as follows:

```
void rctry(context & c)
{
    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    expr y = c.int_const("y");

    expr res = expr(c, Z3_mk_eq(c, x, y)); // res is now a managed expr
#ifdef FAULT_CLAUSE
    expr z = c.int_const("z");
    expr u = c.int_const("u");
    expr fe = expr(c, Z3_mk_eq(c,z,u)); // fe is now a managed expr
#endif
    std::cout << Z3_ast_to_string(c, res) << std::endl;        
}
```

Within the destructor of `expr` there is a call to `Z3_dec_ref`, so that it
will be called automatically at the end of the function, when `res` and `fe` go
out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Really helpful! But how about undefined behavior when accessing objects which are not needed any longer? For example, in original code I add `Z3_dec_ref(c, res);` after `Z3_mk_eq` without defining `FAULT_CLAUSE`, and in result `Z3_ast_to_string` still works and returns correct `(= x y)`. Is it one of undefined behaviors? Thank you!

Comment: One more question, does `Z3_push` and `Z3_pop` effect referencing counts of Z3 objects? If I create an `Z3_ast` between `Z3_push` and `Z3_pop`, does this `Z3_ast` be deallocated after `Z3_pop` method?

Comment: Indeed, access to an invalid memory location has undefined behavior, it does not necessarily mean that your program crashes (this is valid in general, not just for Z3). In this example, the memory didn't get overwritten in the meanwhile, so it still contained the right data "accidentally".

Comment: ASTs (and other Z3 objects) persist for as long as your program holds a reference (i.e., it "owns" 1 ref count), no matter which functions are called. So, no, none of these objects will be deallocated when `Z3_pop` is called.